# Typescript Property 'push' does not exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

Hello I have problem in React-Typescript inside Redux toolkit. I get an error

```
'push' does not exist on type 'string | string[] | WritableDraft<Recipe>[] | WritableDraft<{ recipes: Recipe[]; totalAmount: number; }>'.
  Property 'push' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

How to solve it because it looks that key has a lot of types and I can not get an object using state['key']. How to solve it? I am stuck.

```
export interface InitialState {
  recipes: Recipe[];
  likedRecipes: {
    recipes: Recipe[];
    totalAmount: number;
  };
  recipeTypes: string[];
  recipeTime: string[];
  recipeTitle: string;
  filterTypes: string[];
  filterLengths: string[];
}



 export type FilteringConfiguration = {
  content: string;
  type: typeOfFiltering;
  filterName: Omit<
    keyof InitialState,
    "recipes" | "likedRecipes" | "recipeTitle"
  >;

};
```

redux slice

```
const INITIAL_VALUE: InitialState = {
  recipes: [],
  likedRecipes: {
    recipes: [],
    totalAmount: 0,
  },
  recipeTypes: ["Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner", "Supper"], 
  recipeTime: [
    "Very short (~30min)",
    "short (~1hr)",
    "medium (~3hrs)",
    "Long (~6hrs)",
  ],

  // variables for filtering recipes
  recipeTitle: "",
  filterTypes: [],
  filterLengths: [],
};

const recipeSlice = createSlice({
  name: "recipe",
  initialState: INITIAL_VALUE,
  reducers: {
   addFilters(state, action: PayloadAction<FilteringConfiguration>) {
  const arr = state[action.payload.filterName];
  if (Array.isArray(arr)) arr.push(action.payload.content);
},
```

UPDATE: I edited add filters but I got next error

```
Type 'Omit<keyof InitialState, "recipes" | "likedRecipes" | "recipeTitle">' cannot be used as an index type.
```

Comment: Array.isArray does not seem to narrow down the tpye

it should look like
static isArray(el):el is Array{
  return el instanceof Array
}   (or similar implementation the important bit is the type narrowing)
alternatively you can use arr instanceof Array directly

Comment: I had to push Recipe type it is weird. How to narrow type to just string[]

Answer (score 4):

You are getting this error because it's possible that the type you are using doesn't have a `.push` method.

One way to handle this is check if it's an array before calling `.push`.

```js
const recipeSlice = createSlice({
  name: "recipe",
  initialState: INITIAL_VALUE,
  reducers: {
    addFilters(state, action: PayloadAction<FilteringConfiguration>) {
      const arr = state[action.payload.filterName]
      if (Array.isArray(arr)) arr.push(action.payload.content);
    }, // THERE IS AN ERROR
})
```

This will solve the typescript error, but maybe you would need to do something when it's not an array and it's not possible to call `.push`, probably in a `else` statement.

## Edit:

The biggest problem you have is that you assume all keys from `InitialState` have values that are an array of string (`string[]`), which is not true, because you have a `string`, and object and an array of `Recipe` too.

In `FilteringConfiguration` you define the `content` as `string`, assuming you will always push a `string`, but because you have other values, this type is also incorrect.

I have no idea how to continue with this, because I don't know if you also want to allow to update the other keys of `InitialValues` or not, but on solution would be to also ignore the keys from `InitialValues` that aren't an array of strings.

```js
export type FilteringConfiguration = {
  content: string;
  type: typeOfFiltering;
  filterName: Exclude<keyof InitialState, 'recipes' | 'likedRecipes' | 'recipeTitle'>; // exclude keys that aren't string[]
};
```

You can check the docs for [Exclude](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers)

Comment: I get next error take a look please. I had to push Recipe type, I can not push string.

Comment: @Kay please look at my edit

Comment: Now I get error like this Type 'Omit<keyof InitialState, "recipes" | "likedRecipes" | "recipeTitle">' cannot be used as an index type. About code I get a filterName from component it is fliterTypes and filterLengths. And i want to work like this state["filterLengths"] but i use action.payload.filterName to make it dynamic and do not repeat the code and "if" statements. I have done it with (if action.payload.type === ''something) then push to this but it was repetetive and long code

Comment: @Kay sorry, it's not `Omit` but `Exclude`

Comment: Sir thank you so much, there is no error! It works. I was stuck for 2 days because I am learning typescript by doing and it is my first strongly typed language sometimes it rough to grasp it. Thanks!

Comment: @Kay if that solved your problem, don't forget to upvote and mark it as accepted. You are welcome